# Install OS from .iso format directly on HDD (without using CD or USB)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, iso-image

I have two HHDs on my system. I try to install Linux on second drive from .iso file but i can't manage. I know GRUB is needed to boot Linux from .iso file but isn't it included in exactly this file. What should I do to install OS on HHD then, is it possible at all?

Comment: Yes, it's possible for Grub to boot an ISO - I don't know how - but you can't use Grub from the ISO .

Comment: so there should be previously GRUB installed on drive?

Comment: Don't ask me, I already told you I don't know. Please wait for some answer or comment from someone who knows. :)

Comment: What OS is on the first HD? And why the limitation of no USB/CD?

Comment: on first HDD is linux OS, i actually solve the problem with installing linux OS from .iso on second HDD (read post underneath) but i still don' t what with installing windows OS from .iso file

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed with command:

```
sudo dd if=<os iso file> of=/dev/sd<partition letter> bs=4M && sudo sync
```

It works for Linux but what with windows .iso file?

Comment: Should work the same, as long as the BIOS reads the „ISO“ you are fine

Comment: but BIOS is not responsible for reading .iso file, bootloader do it which is called by BIOS

Comment: Well, does it work or not?

Comment: it works only with linux .iso file, but does not with windows .iso file